# Does the JS plugin "Bootstrap Table" has a method to get all the data currently set on a table as textContent and not that set on its data object?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

So here's the column data for the table, a couple of columns have functions on formatter and success to render their values automatically.

```
var columnasInercia = [
  {field: 'lechoNo', title: 'Lecho Nº', formatter: function(value, row, index) { return index + 1; }},
  {field: 'distancia', title: 'Distancia', editable: {type: 'text'}},
  {field: 'varillaNo', title: 'Varilla Nº', class: 'ColVarillaNo', editable: {type: 'text', success: function(response, newValue) { calcularArea($(this).parent('td'), newValue); }}},
  {field: 'areaVarilla', title: 'Area varilla', class: 'ColAreaVarilla'},
  {field: 'varillasEnLecho', title: 'Varilla en lecho', editable: {type: 'text'}},
];
```

Here's an example of the data populating it at the beginning, since two columns have their values set by events I just pass values for 3 columns.

```
var datosInerciaMayor = [
  {'distancia': '6', 'varillaNo': '10', 'varillasEnLecho': '3'},
  {'distancia': '21', 'varillaNo': '10', 'varillasEnLecho': '2'},
  {'distancia': '36', 'varillaNo': '10', 'varillasEnLecho': '2'},  
];
```

Here's how the table looks:[image: link]

Now the problem is that when I run the `getData`method of the API

`alert(JSON.stringify($('#TablaInerciaMayor').bootstrapTable('getData')));`

I just get data for the 3 columns I populated:

[image: link]

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the following link which lists all of the methods used in bootstrap tables. But to answer your question, no. All of the get row functions will return an object and then you can cast it into whatever you want to work with. Easiest being a map of the data.

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods